# Unresolved Placeholder Validation for Spring Boot Configuration Properties

Tags: spring, validation, spring-boot, configuration, spring-boot-configuration

Given some application configuration with an unresolvable placeholder, like the following `application.yml`

```
my:
  thing: ${missing-placeholder}/whatever
```

When I use `@Value` annotations, the placeholders in the configuration file are validated, so in this case:

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class PropValues {
    @Value("${my.thing}") String thing;
    public String getThing() { return thing; }
}
```

I get an `IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'missing-placeholder' in value "${missing-placeholder}/whatever"`. This is because the value is being set directly by `AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue` and there is nothing to catch the exception thrown by `PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue`

However, looking to move to `@ConfigurationProperties` style I noticed that this validation is missing, for example in this case:

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
public class Props {
    private String thing;
    public String getThing() { return thing; }    
    public void setThing(String thing) { this.thing = thing; }
}
```

there is no exception. I can see `PropertySourcesPropertyValues.getEnumerableProperty` catches the exception with the comment `// Probably could not resolve placeholders, ignore it here` and gathers the invalid value into its internal map. Subsequent data binding does not check for unresolved placeholders.

I checked that simply applying the `@Validated` and `@Valid` annotations to the class and field do not help.

Is there any way to preserve the behaviour of throwing an exception on  unresolved placeholders with `ConfigurationProperties` binding?

Comment: You should but `@Validated` on th class and `@NotNull` or `@NotEmpty` on the field and for validation to work you will have to have a JSR-303 validator on your class path like `hibernate-validation`. Only adding the annotation `@Validation` yields nothing.

Comment: Has anybody found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are no better solutions. At least this is kind of nicer than afterPropertiesSet().

```
@Data
@Validated // enables javax.validation JSR-303
@ConfigurationProperties("my.config")
public static class ConfigProperties {
    // with @ConfigurationProperties (differently than @Value) there is no exception if a placeholder is NOT RESOLVED. So manual validation is required!
    @Pattern(regexp = ".*\$\{.*", message = "unresolved placeholder")
    private String uri;
    // ...
}
```

**UPDATE:** I got the regex wrong the first time. It as to match the entire input (not just `java.util.regex.Matcher#find()`).

Answer (score 0):

The correct regex to pass in `@Pattern` annotation is `^(?!\\$\\{).+`

```
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties("my.config")
public class ConfigProperties {
    
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(?!\\$\\{).+", message = "unresolved placeholder")
    private String uri;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `@ConfigurationProperties` on `Props` where you may set a default value.  You can use the following:

```java
@Value("#{props.getThing()}")
String theThing;
```

This also works well in other SPeL contexts like `Scheduled` for example

```java
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{@dbConfigurationProperties.getExpirationCheckDelayInMs()}")
void cleanup() {
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue exactly 10 minutes ago!
Try to add this bean in your configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
```

Comment: Good find, but in fact that's the solution for the opposite problem. I don't want to hide the error, I want to preserve it.

Comment: you have to do that manually making your properties classes to implement `InitializingBean` and overriding the `afterPropertiesSet()` method you can check by reflection each field's value and throw an exception in case they are null.

Comment: That doesn't sound very elegant, besides the properties don't end up null they end up with the placeholder values still embedded in the string.

Comment: yes I agree, not very elegant. If I find a better way I'll let you know.

Comment: I cannot believe afterPropertiesSet() is the best we have :'(