# @ConfigurationProperties returns property placeholder instead of null

Tags: spring-boot, properties, placeholder, configurationproperties

I have the following **@ConfigurationProperties** property holder:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom.service")
public class CustomServicePropertyHolder {

    private String name;
}
```

and my application.properties looks like this:

```
custom.service.name=${remote.service.name}
custom.service.....=...
custom.service.....=...
```

`remove.service.name` is an environment variable received in the runtime.

However, when `remote.service.name` was not provided, the value of the `EtlConfigurationHolder.name` is a string `"${remote.service.name}"`.

How to make the property to return null instead of this placeholder string ?

Comment: I also encountered this behavior ... I can’t add NotNull validation now

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered such a problem ... And it has been present for a long time

- [Unresolved Placeholder Validation for Spring Boot Configuration Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493346/unresolved-placeholder-validation-for-spring-boot-configuration-properties)
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4302
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1768

I found only one place where at least some solution is attached

https://davidagood.com/spring-boot-fail-on-missing-env-vars/